# What's the difference between "despise" and "scorn" as verbs?

Tags: difference, verbs

What's the difference between "despise" and "scorn" as verbs?

Comment: What definitions have you looked at? Was there something they didn't explain?

Comment: I have read some definitions, and as far as I understand "despise" = "scorn" + "dislike", but I am not sure about it.

Comment: Simply, "to despise" means to hate, and "to scorn" can mean either feeling or expressing derision or contempt. There is overlap between the two words. You can get a large sampling of examples by searching google books.